# "SharePoint Designer Settings" on "Site Collection Administration" not exist on sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

i am Site Collection Administrator and i had activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" on all site collation.
and also enabled  "SharePoint Server Publishing"

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sharepoint designer can and should be enabled on the web application level (CA, application management, manage web applications, pick one, general settings, sharepoint designer).

after it is enabled on the web app level, you will then be able to use it on site collections, provided that you have enough permissions, and you are located in the root site collection

web application settings (central admin)

```
/_admin/WebApplicationList.aspx
```

site collection settings (root site collection)

```
/_layouts/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx
```

Comment: thanks Tiago                                                          i have seen that "Allow Site Owners and Designers to Customize Master Pages and Page Layouts" is disabled by server administrator so it means that i cant enable it by my self even if im site collection owner ?

Comment: exactly. those settings are inherited from the web application level and if enabled, they can then be customized on the site collection level

Comment: can you give me the link of the "site application level" i don't have direct accesses to there .. and i will check if i have promotions to do it .... thanks

Comment: answer updated. you can just ask an admin to enable SPDesigner for your web application

Comment: i have promitions for SP Designer the problem is that i dont have promitions for eCustomize Master-pages ... thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

there are couple environments on sharepoint
one of them is not allowed to work on sharepoint designer and modify things like a master page, the reason is that those sites are less flexible for design but easier to
upgrade the version of the sharepoint environment for example upgrade from SP2010 to SP 2013

so this is the reason that i couldn't see that option